# Difference b/w PBKDF2 implementation in Node.js and Java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, pbkdf2

I'm trying to implement a Java code which generates a PBDKF2 key in Node.js, but the result is different in both the case.
here's the Java code:

```
String passphrase = "1234";
String salt = "1234";
int key_size = 128; //bits
int iteration_count = 1000;
SecretKeySpec key = null;

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), hex(salt), iteration_count, key_size);
key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
System.out.println(hex(key.getEncoded()));

public static byte[] hex(String str) {
    try {
        return Hex.decodeHex(str.toCharArray());
    } catch (DecoderException var2) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(var2);
    }
}
```

Output is: `1b1b653ea60ee1d82ecb22f7f59b7c43`

Node.js code:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var salt = '1234';
var passphrase = '1234';
var keySize = 16; // bytes
var iterationCount = 1000;

crypto.pbkdf2(passphrase, new Buffer(salt), iterationCount, keySize, 'sha1', function(err, key) {
    console.log(key.toString('hex'));
});
```

Output is: `ed5b67e667fa6bca73e1ec21dddda358`

Why are the outputs different? What am I missing here?

Comment: As a check, you can use the [PBKDF2 test vectors at my Giuthub repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-Test-Vectors) to test your implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately they are giving different outputs because you have given them different inputs.

Your Java output matches the result for

```
PBKDF2[HMACSHA1](UTF8("1234"), HEX("1234"), 1000, 16)
```

Your node.js output matches the result for

```
PBKDF2[HMACSHA1](UTF8("1234"), UTF8("1234"), 1000, 16)
```

The difference being that your salt in Java was `{ 0x12, 0x34 }` and in node.js was `{ 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34 }`.

Presumably you want `new Buffer(salt, 'hex')` (or, since [that constructor is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding), `Buffer.from(salt, 'hex')`).

Comment: Ah! Thanks for your answer. It helped resolving the issue.

Comment: @bartonjs what is the other way around to do ? to make java match the node js ?